# How can i detect when user submits the form when using Braintree JavaScript SDK when using hosted fields?

Tags: javascript, sdk, braintree

I see no callback for this event in the Braintree documentation (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#setup-method-options), but i need to show some progress indicator when user submits the form, or presses Enter in one of the fields.

I can hook into the form submit handler, but then pressing Enter in one of the hosted fields does not trigger the form submit event. Also, i cannot access those fields via JavaScript because of the SameOrigin policy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

One approach would be to pass the [`onPaymentMethodReceived`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#setup-method-options) callback as part of the options object in `braintree.setup`. This  callback gets triggered when a payment method nonce is received from Braintree — after the user submits the form, but before anything gets sent to your server. Keep in mind that with this option, Braintree will not submit the form automatically, so you’ll be responsible for sending the payment method nonce and any other form data to your server.

Alternatively, you might be able to use something like a DOM event listener that doesn’t interfere with the form’s submit handler. You also can use the [`onFieldEvent`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/hosted-fields) callback to keep track of the state of each hosted field before the form gets submitted.

If you need more help with the specific details of your implementation, feel free reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: onPaymentMethodReceived gets triggered after the response from the Braintree is received, i need it the moment i made the request.

I managed too hook form submit event, and that is fine, but event is not triggered when i press enter in hosted field. I'll research onFieldEvent and try to use it for this purpose and i'll publish my finding.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! The fact that hitting the enter key bypasses the native submit event is a known issue that we’re working on for the next major version of our SDK. You can check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/155) for more details.

Comment: Great, so it is known issue. Great, thank you. I'll be following mentioned issue for resolution.